# Using iconv on list?

Tags: r, list, vector, iconv

I have a list of about 1000 character vectors in R that I need to convert to `UTF-8`. The only tool that I could find for reliable conversions is `iconv()`, but it only works on character vectors. How can I convert my entire list without smashing it together into a single vector?

Comment: `help("lapply")`

Comment: Give a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve this with the "helpful" answers given by the commenters (but thanks nonetheless, since I figured it out anyways). Assuming this is my original list `list_1`:

```
[[1]] 縺薙ｌ縺ｯ
[[2]] 萓ｿ蛻ｩ縺ｧ縺・
```

I now use `lapply` to iterate the function `iconv` over the entire list, with the arguments for `iconv` simply listed after a comma inside `lapply`:

```
list_1_iconv <- lapply(list_1, iconv, from = "SHIFT-JIS", to = "UTF-8")
```

Which yields:

```
[[1]] これは
[[2]] 便利です
```